# Is it dangerous to have a bathroom floor mat on my heated tile floor?

Tags: tile, floorheating

I'm installing Schluter Ditra Heated Flooring beneath my bathroom tile flooring. I was advised that in doing so, I cannot have a bathroom floor mat because it would cause that area to overheat. Is this true, and if so, is there alternatives? I really don't want to constantly have a wet floor.

Comment: that would be the correct advice

Comment: follow the manufacturer recommendations

Comment: You could always lay a towel down as a bath mat and then pick it up after your shower/bath/whatever.  They just don't want you leaving something in one place permanently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be dangerous, depending on the size and thickness of the mat and the design of your heating.

Why would your floor be constantly wet?  For a heated floor use a lightweight mat (just a thin towel) under your feet after a shower, then wipe the floor and hang it up.  Keep a few of them and throw them in the laundry regularly.

If you want to have a mat in one place all the time (not just after a shower) you can design your floor heating around it.   But why would you?  If that's where you'll be standing, that's where you'll most enjoy the warm floor.   If you do design around it, your vendor should provide a new layout and you may need to buy a shorter cable, depending on the size of the mat.

Comment: Made a sheepskin mat years ago.  Always picked it up off the floor after using.